# Parsing XML after getting location using Utrace

Tags: c#, xml, ip

Hey guys well my idea is simple, I will get location information from an IP address (proxy at example) with Utrace API.

look at this code (thanks google)

```
public static string GetLocation(string IP)
    {
        var location = "";
        List<string> HTML_code = new List<string>();
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://xml.utrace.de/?query=" + IP);
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                HTML_code.Add(line);
            }
        }
        location = (HTML_code[296].Replace("<td><font size=\"-1\">", "")).Replace("</font></td>", "");
        return location;
    }
```

OK but the output from the utrace API is the following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <results>
    <result>
    <ip>188.40.16.134</ip>
    <host></host>
    <isp>Hetzner Online AG Pagedesign</isp>
    <org>Hetzner Online AG Pagedesign</org>
    <region>Koblenz</region>
    <countrycode>DE</countrycode>
    <latitude>50.349998474121</latitude>
    <longitude>7.5999999046326</longitude>
    <queries>8</queries>
    </result>
    </results>
```

My XML skill is not the best I hope you guys can help me to edit this line:

```
location = (HTML_code[296].Replace("<td><font size=\"-1\">", "")).Replace("</font></td>", "");
```

I will an output like this:

```
Hetzner Online AG Pagedesign : Koblenz
```

and not

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <results>
    <result>
    <ip>188.40.16.134</ip>
    <host></host>
    <isp>Hetzner Online AG Pagedesign</isp>
    <org>Hetzner Online AG Pagedesign</org>
    <region>Koblenz</region>
    <countrycode>DE</countrycode>
    <latitude>50.349998474121</latitude>
    <longitude>7.5999999046326</longitude>
    <queries>8</queries>
    </result>
    </results>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Edit:

My new code is following:

```
public static void getloc(string ip)
    {
        var location = "";
        var wc = new WebClient();
       location = wc.DownloadString("http://xml.utrace.de/?query=" + ip);
       location = location.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>", "").Replace("<results>", "").Replace("<result>", "")
           .Replace("<ip></ip>", "").Replace("<org></org>", "").Replace("<latitude></latitude>", "").Replace("<longitude></longitude>", "").Replace("<queries>*</queries>", "")
            .Replace("</result>", "").Replace("</results>", "");  
        Console.WriteLine(location);
    }
```

the output is then :

```
<ip>212.19.62.76</ip>
<host>1</host>
<isp>Plus.line AG</isp>
<org>ANW GmbH &amp; Co. KG</org>
<region>Bechhofen</region>
<countrycode>DE</countrycode>
<latitude>49.150001525879</latitude>
<longitude>10.550000190735</longitude>
<queries>6</queries>
```

How can I get an output like
Plus.line AG ANW GmbH & Co. KG  Bechhofen

Greets and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the XML into an `XmlDocument` and parse it properly.

```
public static void getLoc(string ip)
{
    var wc = new WebClient();
    string location = wc.DownloadString("http://xml.utrace.de/?query=" + ip);

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(location);

    XmlNode orgNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//org/text()");
    XmlNode regionNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//region/text()");

    return String.Format("{0} {1}", orgNode.Value, regionNode.Value);
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you very much this is a wonderfull solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple with Linq to Xml:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result = xdoc.Descendatns("result")
                 .Select(r => new {
                     Org = (string)r.Element("org"),
                     Region = (string)r.Element("region")
                 }).Single();
```

This will return strongly typed anonymous object with properties Org and Region. Formatting:

```
String.Format("{0} : {1}", result.Org, result.Region);
```

Comment: If you are calling that `Select` method call "simple" you have been drinking FAR too much Kool-Aid.

Comment: @JonGrant select is a part of query, which is simple if you know C#. And this particular select is very simple. I believe most of C# programmers will find C++ pointers to be complex. But that's a usual simple thing for C++ programmers.